# Problem with freezing pytorch model - requires_grad is always true

Tags: python, pytorch

I have tried to freeze part of my model but it does not work. Gradient computation is still enabled for each layer. Is that some sort of bug or am I doing something wrong? :)

```py
model = models.resnet18(pretrained=True)

# To freeze the residual layers
for param in model.parameters():
    param.require_grad = False
for param in model.fc.parameters():
    param.require_grad = True

# Replace last layer        
num_features = model.fc.in_features
model.fc = nn.Linear(num_features, 2)
model.fc = nn.Dropout(0.5)

# Find total parameters and trainable parameters
total_params = sum(p.numel() for p in model.parameters())
print(f'{total_params:,} total parameters.')
# >>> 21,284,672 total parameters.

total_trainable_params = sum(p.numel() for p in model.parameters() if p.requires_grad)
print(f'{total_trainable_params:,} training parameters.')
# >>> 21,284,672 training parameters.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of a typo. Change `require_grad` to `requires_grad`:

```
for param in model.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False
for param in model.fc.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = True
```

Currently, you are declaring a new attribute for the model and assigning it to `True` and `False` as appropriate, so it has no effect.

Comment: Wow, thank you! It's so comical but yet i have spent few hours wondering what was wrong with my code! Thanks once again!

Answer (score 2):

This is just a typo (`require_grad` must be `requires_grad`):

```py
# To freeze the residual layers
for param in model.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False  # it was require_grad 
for param in model.fc.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = True  # it was require_grad
```